# Role of class priors in Weka classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

I have a training set of data consisting of some 1568 rows, each of which has one of seven values of the class attribute. I am seeking to test this data on a second dataset of 168 rows.

But I have a question. Weka reports that 'class priors' are:

```
141.0
169.0
225.0
197.0
421.0
281.0
141.0
```

My training set has the following number of instances per class attribute value:

```
140
168
224
196
420
280
140
```

Apart from the class priors being very closely related to the training set row counts per value of the class attribute, can anyone tell me what they are and what they actually represent?

The testing set has the following number of instances per class attribute value:

```
15
18
24
21
45
30
15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class prior is an estimate of the probability that randomly sampling an instance from a population will yield the given class (regardless of any attributes of the instance).  Weka is assuming that your training data are randomly drawn from a population such that the proportions of classes in your training set are indicative of their relative abundance in the sampled population.  Note that what Weka is reporting are not the priors but the counts used to calculate the priors.  The reason for the addition of 1 to each count is to prevent a zero count in a situation where a particular class isn't represented in your training data.  So Weka should compute the actual priors for each class as

```
P(c_i) = n_i / (N + C)
```

where `n_i` is the number of samples for class `i`, `N` is the total number of samples, and `C` is the number of classes.

As a very simple example of what the prior probability is used for, consider classifying an illness, knowing only that a person has a fever and a headache.  These symptoms are indications of both influenza and of Ebola virus.  But far more people have the flu than Ebola (the prior probability of influenza is much higher than that of Ebola) so based on those symptoms, you would classify the illness as the flu.

Weka provides methods to update or override the default prior probabilities.  To see the mathematical detail of how prior probabilities are used in classification, look at [Bayes' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).